# Show that $\frac{x+0.5}{(1+x)x} > \ln(1+1/x)$ for $x \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show this to prove a real analysis result. I'm not sure what inequalities I can use to show this result. I'd be glad for help or a hint!

Edit: The original question asked to show that the sequence $a_n = \frac{n!e^n}{n^{n+0.5}}$ is decreasing. Taking the ratio $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$, I obtained $\frac{(1+1/n)^{n+0.5}}{e}$; the task reduces to showing that the numerator is greater than e. Noting that it tends to e as n tends to infinity, the task simplifies to showing that the numerator is a decreasing function on the positive reals.

Taking logs and differentiating, the problem amounts to proving the inequality originally asked, which is where I hit a roadblock. My first idea was that the inequality $x > \ln(1+x)$ would be helpful, but it doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun, thank you for the clarification; I've updated the post with further context and background. I had not considered the wider framing to be relevant to prospective answerers, and really, most of my work on this specific problem has amounted to a lot of scratched out symbols, so I'd omitted it. I'll be mindful to include it in future posts.

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for editing your answer. I have already converted my downvote to an upvote and retracted my vote to close.

Comment: Well, it seems to be true for x > 0.

Comment: Let z = 1/x. For large x, the left hand side is about z - z^2/2 + z^3/2, the right hand side about z - z^2/2 + z^3/3. I'd subtract z = z^2/2 + z^3/3 from both sides and see if what is left is easy to compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is enough to exploit convexity. For any $x\geq 1$ (for any $x>0$ as well)

$$ \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) = \int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}<\frac{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+1}}{2} = \frac{x+1/2}{x(x+1)} $$
since the area described by the integral is bounded by the area of a trapezoid, due to the convexity of $\frac{1}{t}$.
$$\phantom{}$$
[image]